# Can I negate a "free" GM intrusion?

Tags: numenera, cypher-system

In Numenera, when a player rolls a 1, the GM gets a free intrusion (Core Rulebook, p.88)

> The GM makes a free intrusion (see 
>   below) and doesn’t award experience points (XP) for 
>   it.

However, it does not state anything about paying experience to negate it, such is the case when the GM offers an intrusion.

**So can I pay experience points to negate the intrusion caused by rolling a 1?**

The reason I ask this is because in my group, I'm not sure if this is house-ruled or not, but it's the way the GM plays it, and always has: when a player rolls a natural 1, the GM gets a free intervention. The player can then choose to re-roll the one, but the intervention stands. If they roll another natural 1, the GM gets *another* intervention. I would like to clarify if this is house ruled, or if this follows the rule book.

Comment: Related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/31905/how-to-ensure-players-spend-xp-on-both-short-and-long-term-benefits-in-numenera

Comment: @omnibus I would advise against tagging every numenera question with the cypher-system tag.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

"Free intrusion" is not a game term and no other rules reference it. Thus beside the rules written on p.88 there are no other restrictions. The general rules for negating intrusions, from p.18:

> the player can refuse the GM intrusion. If he does so, he doesn’t get
>   the 2 XP from the GM, and he must also spend 1 XP that he already has.
>   If the player has no XP to spend, he can’t refuse the intrusion.

are still in effect. **Yes, you can refuse** a nat1 "induced" GM intrusion by paying an XP.

Comment: It may actually be a good idea to mention the possibility of simply rerolling the nat 1. The roll of a 1 means you'll fail the task, even if the GM doesn't get an intrusion and with a reroll you could still succeed; there's  a high chance of avoiding the intrusion (95%), but there's a small chance(5%) that the xp is wasted.